# Solution for VB6 to broadcast Webcam

Tags: vb6, ffmpeg, streaming, webcam

Sorry, I know VB6 is decades ago, but I'm in a situation that I have to use VB6 to deliver live webcam stream beetween 2 PC in Server - Client Model program. Vb6-code holds the connection then I have no choice but to transfer all data via that connection.

I've tried weeks for this, uncountable approaches but went to nowhere.
My efforts focused on 3 major approaches:

**1/ Use ffmpeg to record** live webcam as ".avi" file on hard disk, transfer parts of file to other end & play it. But I've stucked with a media-player that can play a "being written" avi file.

Windows Media Player control told me "file already in use..." & VLC Plugin can't even be added to VB6 (axvlc.dll).

**2/ Use ffmpeg to save live webcam** as avi file, transfer each bit of that file to the other end, then in other end, extract 24 images / second from the avi to display continously in a picture box.
This approach is ok except that my hard disk get fulled of images  in a time of wink and my program get very slow before hanging.

**3/ Use ffmpeg to stream** the live webcam to a rtp-port like this:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Lenovo EasyCamera" -vcodec mpeg2video -pix_fmt yuv422p -f rtp -an rtp://224.1.2.3:8191
```

I've successfully watch the stream in VLC, but VLC(axvlc.dll) refused to be integrated into ancient VB6. And more important, I don't know how to redirect/reroute the rtp stream to other PC with VB6.

Any one please light me up? (Any 3rd party component is welcomed)

Comment: If all you are doing is offloading the work to ffmpeg or VLC, why does it have to be VB6?  A) Arent there numerous ready-to-use webcam apps around?  B) Have you considered DirectShow? There are other old-tech options (but links to some I used to use are now as dead as VB6) it is just hard to tell exactly what you are after based on what you tried.  Finally, if #2 works, why not refine that to delete images already shown?

Comment: @Plutonix: It's a complicated situation that I have to use VB6. But the major reason is that I MUST transfer all data between 2 PC using a TCP/UDP-connection created by VB6 code. And I've never heard about any technique that can share a connection between 2 separated program, so I'm stucked with VB6 and a small set of components/techniques that are compatible with VB6. The reason why #2 is not feasible is that creating/displaying/deleting 24 images of size ~100kb every seconds is not a stable solution, it's greedy for resources & the HDD get fragmented soon.

Comment: @Plutonix: The fact that I have to transfer all data via a pre-installed connection by VB6  eliminated almost all the ready-to-use solutions that are incompatible with VB6

Answer (score 3):

After some research it seems that Microsoft uses rtsp which is a variation of the rtp protocol.  Fortunately ffmpeg supports muxing and demuxing in that format. https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtsp .  You may have to adjust the parameters outlined.
If the server must be a vb6 frontend, you can have ffmpeg launched as the backend from the command line. This is a common method and I found an example of it here: https://www.ehow.com/how_6038708_use-ffmpeg-visual-basic-6.html for reference.

The next stage is the ability to play those streams in visual basic 6.  What you can do is add a Windows Media Player control and set its property WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL to {a list with your url added to it as a string}.
One version of control has a id of {6BF52A50-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6} and the dll is wmp.dll.  Make sure the control has autoStart & invokeURLs set to true.

Some other things worth mentioning is trying to use WMP compliant codecs and contains such as windows media video.

Comment: Thanks for taking time researching on this stuff. Your solution would be perfect except the fact that VB6 holds the connection. When FFMPEG broadcasts the live signal, it could only broadcast RTSP **locally** but VB6 is the one that transfer the signal over the internet to the other end. So, do you have any trick to make VB6 redirect a local rtsp protocol through internet to the other PC?

Comment: Your situation seems to be pretty constrained and I am having a bit of difficulty understanding just how limited you are from your statement. Perhaps an echo server would work, it would receive local broadcasts and you can modify the packets including their address and then send them to as many clients as you wish.  Here is an example: http://www.planetsourcecode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=39661&lngWId=1

Comment: I don't think it is hard to understand. If you use ffmpeg to broad cast : "ffmpeg .... rtsp:1.2.3.4:1234", ffmpeg will make its own port listening, when someone connect to that port, ffmpeg will establish its own connection. That's failed because I can only use VB6 to listen to certain port and establish VB6's own connection when someone connect. So, the solution is to make ffmpeg broadcast to localhost, then VB6 MUST pretend/mimic that it is the real ffmpeg to the other PC somehow. But I don't know how to pretend/mimic!